# ESP8266 SPIFFS not saving correctly?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, c++, json

Hey all I am having some issues with the SPIFFS for this Wemos D1 mini ESP8266 controller.

This is my Arduino sketch:

```
#include <FS.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

struct RGBLA {
  uint8_t R;
  uint8_t G;
  uint8_t B;
  uint8_t L;
  uint8_t A;
};

void setup() {
  if (!SPIFFS.begin()) {
    Serial.println("error while mounting filesystem!");
  } else {    
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    RGBLA returnedVars = readSPIFFS();

    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Starting...");

    Serial.println("readSPIFFS 1");
    Serial.print("R: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.R);
    Serial.print("G: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.G);
    Serial.print("B: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.B);
    Serial.print("L: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.L);
    Serial.print("AmbientLight: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.A);

    Serial.println("==================================");

    returnedVars = saveToSPIFFS(25,77, 107, 250, 155, false);  
    Serial.println("saveToSPIFFS #1");
    Serial.print("R: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.R);
    Serial.print("G: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.G);
    Serial.print("B: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.B);
    Serial.print("L: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.L);
    Serial.print("AmbientLight: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.A);

    Serial.println("==================================");

    returnedVars = saveToSPIFFS(205,17, 68, 50, 15, true);
    Serial.println("saveToSPIFFS #2");
    Serial.print("R: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.R);
    Serial.print("G: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.G);
    Serial.print("B: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.B);
    Serial.print("L: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.L);
    Serial.print("AmbientLight: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.A);

    returnedVars = readSPIFFS();
    Serial.println("readSPIFFS 2");
    Serial.print("R: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.R);
    Serial.print("G: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.G);
    Serial.print("B: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.B);
    Serial.print("L: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.L);
    Serial.print("AmbientLight: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.A);

    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("END!");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}

RGBLA saveToSPIFFS(uint8_t R, uint8_t G, uint8_t B, uint8_t L, uint8_t A, bool saveA) {
  File configFile = SPIFFS.open("/config.json", "w+");

  if (configFile.size() > 3072) {
    Serial.println("Config file size is too large.");
  } else {
    Serial.print("Writing json to Config file...");

    StaticJsonBuffer<200> jsonBuffer;
    JsonObject& json = jsonBuffer.createObject();

    //Get the old value and save it
    RGBLA returnedVars = readSPIFFS();

    Serial.println("Old Values?");
    Serial.print("R: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.R);
    Serial.print("G: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.G);
    Serial.print("B: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.B);
    Serial.print("L: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.L);
    Serial.print("AmbientLight: ");
    Serial.println(returnedVars.A);

    if (saveA) {
      //Save Ambient Light data
      json["R"] = returnedVars.R;
      json["G"] = returnedVars.G;
      json["B"] = returnedVars.B;
      json["L"] = returnedVars.L;
      json["A"] = A;

      //Now save the new data
      returnedVars.A = A;
    } else {
      //Save RGBL data
      json["R"] = R;
      json["G"] = G;
      json["B"] = B;
      json["L"] = L;   
      json["A"] = returnedVars.A;

      //Now save the new data
      returnedVars.R = R;
      returnedVars.G = G;
      returnedVars.B = B;
      returnedVars.L = L;
    }

    json.printTo(configFile);
    configFile.close();

    //Read new saved values into struct
    //returnedVars = readSPIFFS();
    return returnedVars;
  }
}

RGBLA readSPIFFS() {
  bool exist = SPIFFS.exists("/config.json");

  if (exist) {
    Serial.println("YAY!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Boo!");
  }

  File configFile = SPIFFS.open("/config.json", "r");
  std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[configFile.size()]);
  configFile.readBytes(buf.get(), configFile.size());
  DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject& json = jsonBuffer.parseObject(buf.get());  
  RGBLA returnedVars;

  String debugLogData;
  json.printTo(debugLogData);

  Serial.println("===============");
  Serial.println(debugLogData);
  Serial.println("===============");
  returnedVars.R = json["R"];
  returnedVars.G = json["G"];
  returnedVars.B = json["B"];
  returnedVars.L = json["L"];
  returnedVars.A = json["A"];

  configFile.close();

  return returnedVars;
}
```

And this is the console output:

```
Starting...
readSPIFFS 1
R: 0
G: 0
B: 0
L: 0
AmbientLight: 25
==================================
Writing json to Config file...YAY!
===============
{}
===============
Old Values?
R: 0
G: 0
B: 0
L: 0
AmbientLight: 0
saveToSPIFFS #1
R: 25
G: 77
B: 107
L: 250
AmbientLight: 0
==================================
Writing json to Config file...YAY!
===============
{}
===============
Old Values?
R: 0
G: 0
B: 0
L: 0
AmbientLight: 0
saveToSPIFFS #2
R: 0
G: 0
B: 0
L: 0
AmbientLight: 25
YAY!
===============
{"R":0,"G":0,"B":0,"L":0,"A":25}
===============
readSPIFFS 2
R: 0
G: 0
B: 0
L: 0
AmbientLight: 25

END!
```

As you can see, the first **old values** has all **0's** which is incorrect. **AmbientLight** should be **25** at that point since **readSPIFFS 1** has **25**. So this should read:

```
Old Values?
R: 0
G: 0
B: 0
L: 0
AmbientLight: 25
```

**saveToSPIFFS #1** is sending values **25, 77, 107, 250, 155 and false** which then outputs correctly as:

```
R: 25
G: 77
B: 107
L: 250
AmbientLight: 0
```

But this time **AmbientLight** should still be **25** since it was sent **false**. It should have taken the **old value (25)** and placed it into the newer save.

```
R: 25
G: 77
B: 107
L: 250
AmbientLight: 25
```

Moving on to **saveToSPIFFS #2** the values again are incorrect. The **AmbientLight** however is correct here. Instead of this output:

```
R: 0
G: 0
B: 0
L: 0
AmbientLight: 25
```

it should be gathering the **4** previous **old values**:

```
R: 25
G: 77
B: 107
L: 250
AmbientLight: 25
```

The json after this should not be this:

```
{"R":0,"G":0,"B":0,"L":0,"A":25}
```

It should be this:

```
{"R":250,"G":77,"B":107,"L":250,"A":25}
```

And lastly, the output of **readSPIFFS 2**:

```
R: 0
G: 0
B: 0
L: 0
AmbientLight: 25
```

Is incorrect. It should output:

```
R: 25
G: 77
B: 107
L: 250
AmbientLight: 25
```

Then after a **reset** it should have that and not the below for **readSPIFFS 1**:

```
R: 0
G: 0
B: 0
L: 0
AmbientLight: 25
```

So, where am I messing up here?

**UPDATE**

```
struct RGBLA {
  uint8_t R;
  uint8_t G;
  uint8_t B;
  uint8_t L;
  uint8_t A;
};

void setup() {
   RGBLA returnedValues = readSPIFFS();

   Serial.println("readSPIFFS 1");
   Serial.print("R: ");
   Serial.println(returnedVars.R);
   Serial.print("G: ");
   Serial.println(returnedVars.G);
   Serial.print("B: ");
   Serial.println(returnedVars.B);
   Serial.print("L: ");
   Serial.println(returnedVars.L);
   Serial.print("AmbientLight: ");
   Serial.println(returnedVars.A);

   returnedValues = saveToSPIFFS(205, 17, 68, 50, 15, false);

   Serial.println("saveToSPIFFS 1");
   Serial.print("R: ");
   Serial.println(returnedVars.R);
   Serial.print("G: ");
   Serial.println(returnedVars.G);
   Serial.print("B: ");
   Serial.println(returnedVars.B);
   Serial.print("L: ");
   Serial.println(returnedVars.L);
   Serial.print("AmbientLight: ");
   Serial.println(returnedVars.A);
}

RGBLA readSPIFFS() {    
   RGBLA returnedVars;
   File configFile = SPIFFS.open("/config.json", "r");

   if (configFile ) {
     Serial.println("YAY!");
     configFile.readBytes((byte*) &returnedValues, sizeof(RGBLA));
     configFile.close();
   } else {
     Serial.println("Boo!");
   }

   return returnedValues;
}

RGBLA saveToSPIFFS() {    
   File configFile = SPIFFS.open("/config.json", "w+");

   if (configFile.size() > 3072) {
     Serial.println("Config file size is too large.");
   } else {
     Serial.print("Writing to Config file...");

     //Get the old value and save it
     RGBLA returnedVars = readSPIFFS();

     Serial.println("Old Values:");
     Serial.print("R: ");
     Serial.println(returnedVars.R);
     Serial.print("G: ");
     Serial.println(returnedVars.G);
     Serial.print("B: ");
     Serial.println(returnedVars.B);
     Serial.print("L: ");
     Serial.println(returnedVars.L);
     Serial.print("AmbientLight: ");
     Serial.println(returnedVars.A);

     if (saveA) {
       //Save Ambient Light data
       returnedVars.A = A;
     } else {
       //Save RGBL data
       returnedVars.R = R;
       returnedVars.G = G;
       returnedVars.B = B;
       returnedVars.L = L;
     }

     configFile.write((byte*) &returnedVars, sizeof(RGBLA));
     configFile.close();

     return returnedVars;
}
```

Comment: why do you save it as JSON? simple `file.write((byte*) rgbla, sizeof (RGBLA))` and `file.read((byte*) rgbla, sizeof (RGBLA))` would work

Comment: @Juraj  can you put that as a potential answer and provide an example?

Comment: if it will be only one instance of the RGBLA struct and one file to save it, then create one global instance of the struct and rather  return a succes state from functions

Answer (score 2):

You can write a struct to file as binary data. This example is from my project.

global data:

```
struct Stats {
  int heatingTime; // minutes
  int consumedPower; // watts
};

Stats statsData;
```

snippet from setup():

```
  File file = SPIFFS.open(STATS_FILENAME, "r");
  if (file) {
    file.readBytes((byte*) &statsData, sizeof(statsData));
    file.close();
  }
```

snippet from statsSave() function:

```
  File file = SPIFFS.open(STATS_FILENAME, "w");
  if (file) {
    file.write((byte*) &statsData, sizeof(statsData));
    file.close();
  }
```

your updated readSPIFFS should be:

```
RGBLA readSPIFFS() {

  RGBLA returnedVars;
  File configFile = SPIFFS.open("/config.json", "r");
  if (configFile ) {
    Serial.println("YAY!");
    configFile.readBytes((byte*) &returnedValues, sizeof(RGBLA));
    configFile.close();
  } else {
    Serial.println("Boo!");
  }
  return returnedValues;
}
```

Comment: So I can still return **RGBLA** like **RGBLA returnedVars = readSPIFFS();**?

Comment: Check out my updated OP.

Comment: `configFile.readBytes((byte*) &returnedValues, sizeof(returnedValues));` or `configFile.readBytes((byte*) &returnedValues, sizeof(RGBLA));`

Comment: Alright corrected that in the update. Do I still need to use **return returnedVars;** or is it already populating the strut?

Comment: what is `configFile["R"]`?

Comment: Getting the value for **R** in the **RGBLA.**

Comment: you read it to the struct with readbytes. it is in returnedValues after readBytes

Comment: Alright I updated the OP again to reflect the changes. Is it correct now?

Comment: you read into local variable returnedValues and `return` copies the struct values into returnedValues in variable in setup

Comment: Ok I updated the OP again to reflect those changes. I also added the **saveToSPIFFS** but I am unsure how to save it as it has old data that needs to be saved with the new data (example: RGBL is new data while A is old data) all that needs to be saved into that config file.

Comment: Ok I think I have it now. Updated the OP update.

Comment: After finally being able to test this out i am getting the error of **invalid conversion from 'byte* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]**

Comment: **invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'const uint8_t* {aka const unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]**

Comment: change cast to required type. those are only different names for byte.